# How to get filter value and sum value in Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have the following array

```
Array
(   [0] => GenderEn: "Male", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi"
    [1] => GenderEn: "Male", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi"
    [2] => GenderEn: "Female", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi"
    [3] => GenderEn: "Female", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi"
    [4] => GenderEn: "Male", ProvinceEn: "BKK"
    [5] => GenderEn: "Female", ProvinceEn: "BKK
)
```

Then I want to create this array from it:

```
Array
(   [0] => Male: "2", Female: "2" Sum : "4" Province : "Chonburi"
    [1] => Male: "1", Female: "1" Sum : "2" Province : "BKK"
)
```

How can I do so?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an object to store the information, with the province as the key.

```js
const arr = [
  {GenderEn: "Male", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi"},
  {GenderEn: "Male", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi"},
  {GenderEn: "Female", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi"},
  {GenderEn: "Female", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi"},
  {GenderEn: "Male", ProvinceEn: "BKK"},
  {GenderEn: "Female", ProvinceEn: "BKK"}
];
var res = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((acc,{GenderEn: gender, ProvinceEn: Province})=>{
    const p = acc[Province] = acc.hasOwnProperty(Province)?acc[Province]: {Male: 0, Female: 0, Sum: 0, Province};
    p[gender]++, p.Sum++;
    return acc;
  }, {})
);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I came here to answer, but I also learned something. I've never instantiated an object with my arguments in a reduce function.  +1

Comment: Thank you so much @hev1

Comment: @NokPollawat No problem.

Comment: Could you give me to your answer ? @JohnPavek

Comment: why this `(acc[province][gender] || 0)` superfluous checks with a default if this case never happens?

Comment: Your answer is helpful, I appreciate it @hev1

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

You must first group your data by a key, in this case `ProvinceEn`. After you have your groups, you can map the statistics to new objects.

I provided generic grouping and summarization functions.

```js
const rawData = [
  { "GenderEn": "Male"   , "ProvinceEn": "Chonburi" },
  { "GenderEn": "Male"   , "ProvinceEn": "Chonburi" },
  { "GenderEn": "Female" , "ProvinceEn": "Chonburi" },
  { "GenderEn": "Female" , "ProvinceEn": "Chonburi" },
  { "GenderEn": "Male"   , "ProvinceEn": "BKK"      },
  { "GenderEn": "Female" , "ProvinceEn": "BKK"      }
]

const count = (data, key, value) =>
  data.filter(item => item[key] === value).length

const groupBy = (data, key) =>
  data.reduce((groups, item) =>
    (existingArr => ({...groups, [item[key]]: [...existingArr, item]}))
    (groups[item[key]] || []), {})

const summarize = (data, groupKey, mapper) =>
  (groups => Object.entries(groups).map(entry => mapper.apply(null, entry)))
  (groupBy(data, groupKey))

console.log(summarize(rawData, 'ProvinceEn', (key, data) => ({
  'Male'       : count(data, 'GenderEn', 'Male'),
  'Female'     : count(data, 'GenderEn', 'Female'),
  'Sum'        : data.length,
  'ProvinceEn' : key
})))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

This is what the code above would look like if it were monolithic. It is very LISP-like. ;)

```js
const rawData = [
  { "GenderEn": "Male"   , "ProvinceEn": "Chonburi" },
  { "GenderEn": "Male"   , "ProvinceEn": "Chonburi" },
  { "GenderEn": "Female" , "ProvinceEn": "Chonburi" },
  { "GenderEn": "Female" , "ProvinceEn": "Chonburi" },
  { "GenderEn": "Male"   , "ProvinceEn": "BKK"      },
  { "GenderEn": "Female" , "ProvinceEn": "BKK"      }
]

const summary = (groups =>
  Object.keys(groups).map(key => ({
    'Male'       : groups[key].filter(item => item['GenderEn'] === 'Male').length,
    'Female'     : groups[key].filter(item => item['GenderEn'] === 'Female').length,
    'Sum'        : groups[key].length,
    'ProvinceEn' : key
  })))
  (rawData.reduce((groups, item) =>
    (existingArr => ({...groups, [item['ProvinceEn']]: [...existingArr, item]}))
    (groups[item['ProvinceEn']] || []), {}), 'ProvinceEn')

console.log(summary)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Mr. Polywhirl

Answer (score 1):

```js
const test = [
{GenderEn: "Male", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi"},
{GenderEn: "Male", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi"},
{GenderEn: "Female", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi"},
{GenderEn: "Female", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi"},
{GenderEn: "Male", ProvinceEn: "BKK"},
{GenderEn: "Female", ProvinceEn: "BKK"}
]


function getProvinceSum(arr){
  return arr.reduce((output, arrObj) => {
    if(!output.some(outputObj => outputObj.Province == arrObj.ProvinceEn)){
      output.push({
        Male: arrObj.GenderEn == "Male" ? 1 : 0,
        Female: arrObj.GenderEn == "Female" ? 1 : 0,
        Sum: 1,
        Province: arrObj.ProvinceEn
      });
    }else{
      const outputObj = output.find(outputObj => outputObj.Province == arrObj.ProvinceEn);
      arrObj.GenderEn == "Male" ? outputObj.Male += 1 : outputObj.Female += 1;
      outputObj.Sum += 1;
    }
    return output; 
  },[]);
}

console.log(getProvinceSum(test));
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets break out the [object bracket syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Description) and [object getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for this one!
Since you specifically asked for an array as output, as opposed to an object:

```js
const data = [
  {GenderEn: "Male", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi"},
  {GenderEn: "Male", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi"},
  {GenderEn: "Female", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi"},
  {GenderEn: "Female", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi"},
  {GenderEn: "Male", ProvinceEn: "BKK"},
  {GenderEn: "Female", ProvinceEn: "BKK"}
];

var output = [];

for (entry of data) {
  let el = output.find(e => e.Province == entry.ProvinceEn);
  if (el) { //If output does contain province entry, add data to it
    el[entry.GenderEn]++;
  }
  else { //Else, create it
    output.push({
      Male: entry.GenderEn == 'Male' ? 1 : 0,
      Female: entry.GenderEn == 'Female' ? 1 : 0,
      get Sum() { //If sum is a getter, you'll never have to set it manually
        return this.Male + this.Female;
      },
      Province: entry.ProvinceEn,
    });
  }
}

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a *simple approach* by using a default object for unknown provinces and sum the parts to get grouped sums for each province.

```js
var data = [{ GenderEn: "Male", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi" }, { GenderEn: "Male", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi" }, { GenderEn: "Female", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi" }, { GenderEn: "Female", ProvinceEn: "Chonburi" }, { GenderEn: "Male", ProvinceEn: "BKK" }, { GenderEn: "Female", ProvinceEn: "BKK" }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { GenderEn, ProvinceEn: Province }) => {
        if (!r[Province]) r[Province] = { Male: 0, Female: 0, Sum: 0, Province };
        r[Province][GenderEn]++;
        r[Province].Sum++;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```